# How do I delete a subset of mesh's from a scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I create multiple mesh's with the same name I can't select them all when I want to remove them from a scene.

I've tried traversing the function to no avail.

```
event.preventDefault();

scene.traverse(function(child) {
   if (child.name === "blueTiles") {
      var remove_object = scene.getObjectByName( "blueTiles", true );
      scene.remove(remove_object); 
   }
});

var surroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x154995, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, opacity: 0.8 });
surroundingCubes = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, surroundMaterial );
scene.add( surroundingCubes );
surroundingCubes.name = "blueTiles";
surroundingCubes.position.set(selectedObject.position.x - 1, 0.11, selectedObject.position.z);

var surroundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x154995, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, opacity: 0.8 });
surroundingCubes = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, surroundMaterial );
scene.add( surroundingCubes );
surroundingCubes.name = "blueTiles";
surroundingCubes.position.set(selectedObject.position.x + 1, 0.11, selectedObject.position.z);
surroundingCubes.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
```

I should be able to only delete all the objects with the name blueTiles

**EDIT I switched from names to Groups, and that worked wonders
SOLUTION BELOW**

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

for (var i = group.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    group.remove(group.children[i]);
}

var surroundingMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x154995, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, opacity: 0.8 });
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1);

if ( selectedObject.position.x - 1 >= 0) {
    surroundingCube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, surroundingMaterial );
    surroundingCube.position.set(selectedObject.position.x - 1, 0.11, selectedObject.position.z);
    surroundingCube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    group.add(surroundingCube);

}

if ( selectedObject.position.x + 1 <= 9) {
    surroundingCube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, surroundingMaterial );
    surroundingCube.position.set(selectedObject.position.x + 1, 0.11, selectedObject.position.z);
    surroundingCube.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    group.add(surroundingCube);

}

scene.add( group );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried grouping them before adding them to the scene? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group

Comment: @Xedret I think this is the actual solution, I decided to tweak the code to use Groups and it seems like a much better solution.

Comment: Should I add it as the answer?

Comment: @Xedret if you add your answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a basic example on how to group meshes with THREE.Group()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try grouping the meshes using the THREE.group class.

A very basic usage would be something like:

```
var meshes = new THREE.Group();
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
meshes.add( mesh1 );
meshes.add( mesh2 );
meshes.add( mesh3 );
scene.add( meshes );
```

Comment: Thanks Xedret, having a group seems to be by far the easier way!

Answer (score 1):

[getObjectByName](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r104/src/core/Object3D.js#L442) just calls [getObjectByProperty](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r104/src/core/Object3D.js#L448) (using the name property) which only returns the first object it finds.
You really just need to loop over `children` of the scene / object3d, check their name, and remove.
If you know all the ones you want to remove will be at the top level it is simple.
Something like....(untested)

```
for ( var i = 0, l = scene.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
  if (scene.children[i].name === 'blueTiles') {
    scene.remove(scene.children[i]);
  }
}
```

If you also want to check at lower levels, you probably want some sort of recursion.

**EDIT...

After having another look at your question..and remembering that there is a traverse function**
You seem to already be traversing the scene and have access to the child.
I think you just need to change your function (and not call getObjectByName at all).

```
scene.traverse(function(child) {
   if (child.name === "blueTiles") {
      scene.remove(child); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Sorry @2pha but that didn't seem to do it, luckily a comment above me outlined Groups and I think that's exactly what I should have done from the start. I'll update my question with the answer.

Comment: yeh, adding them to a group before adding to the scene is a better way. Another option would be just to keep references to all your "blueTiles" objects, in an array perhaps.